# Are there statistics showing the usage over time of open source implementations of programming languages compilers/interpreters?

Tags: history, statistics

Many programming languages have popular open-source implementations: C, C++, Java, Javascript, Python, C#, PHP.

Does statistical data exist that shows how much of the software (open source or not) is built with open source compilers or interpreters and how much with closed source? And does the data provide historical data, so that it can be seen if the usage of open-source development systems in programming has increased or decreased over time?

Comment: What do you mean by "programmed with"?

Comment: I edited to clarify.

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want to know if people (who?) use a proprietary Java implementation or the Free Software version?

Comment: @Tichodrama: I want statistics, how much software is developed with OSS-compilers (be it GCC, OpenJDK, Python) in comparison to closed-source compilers (standard Java, Visual C++) and how this developed over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [data from blackduck](https://www.blackducksoftware.com/resources/data) isn't broken down by open/closed compilers, but it does cover the specific languages and provide historical information.

Additionally, it is focused on language use solely within open source projects. Obtaining this information for closed/proprietary projects is obviously problematic.

With the possible exception of the Visual Studio/.NET specific languages such as VB.NET, and probably C# and Apple's objective C, I suspect that most of the compiled language use is from `gcc` (which is, of course, more than just a `c` or `c++` compiler).

This is especially likely as I doubt too many open source projects use proprietary compilers, as the cost is a barrier to contributions.

This is the closest I've been able to find in the ten days since you asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe_index has language use history.  It does not, however, specify the compiler.  Still, very interesting.